# Dynamical localisation in delta-kicked rotor

Tags: quantum-mechanics, chaos-theory

The quantum delta-kicked rotor is a common tool for studying quantum chaos. The energy of the rotor increases ballistically when kicking at the [Talbot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talbot_effect) time (resonance) and jumps between zero and some finite value when kicking at half the Talbot time (anti-resonance).

Another case is **dynamical localisation**, when kicking occurs at some irrational multiple of the Talbot time. The energy grows linearly until the qwuantum break time, after which the energy levels out as you increase the number of kicks.

I (more or less) understand the mathematics of the problem (e.g. from Reichl's *The Transition to Chaos*). The problem is just understanding this in a physical sense, because there is very little out there that gives a good description.

So what is a solid (but Math-lite) description of dynamical localization?